# How can I start another activity with putextra class objects?

Tags: android-studio, navigation, mapbox, start-activity

I want to start another activity with some set class object like *NavigationViewOptions*.

My code:

```
 public NavigationViewOptions options;

 options=NavigationViewOptions.builder()
                    .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                    .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
                    .navigationListener(MainActivity.this)
                    .build();

            Intent navigationActivity=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavigationActivity.class);
            navigationActivity.putExtra("navigationOptions", options); startActivity(navigationActivity);
```

And what I got build error "no suitable method for putextra"

Then I tried *(Parselable)options* or *(Serializable)options* like below

```
navigationActivity.putExtra("navigationOptions", (Parcelable) options);

navigationActivity.putExtra("navigationOptions", (Serializable) options);
```

I got build successful. But when I was running app on device, I got errors

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mapbox_document, PID: 18374
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.AutoValue_NavigationViewOptions cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
    at com.example.mapbox_document.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:236)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7346)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14275)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7312)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27794)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7100)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

I tried to add parcelable method to mainactivity class extends but I failed.

What is the method I have to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing non primitive types via an intent between activities, you have 2 options:

Make the object **parcelable** or make it **serializable**.

In order for it to be parcelable (a parcel can be created from it), the NavigationViewOptions class would have to implement the Parcelable interface.

In order for it to be serializable (convertable from and to byte stream) the NavigationViewOptions class would have to implement the Serializable interface.

For reference have a look here: https://www.techjini.com/blog/passing-objects-via-intent-in-android/

Checking the implementation of NavigationViewOptions, I cannot find the implementation of neither the serializable nor the parcelable interface. Therefore passing the NavigationViewOptions object via an intent is not straightforward.

**Recommendation:**

I would recommend you to pass the primitive objects, that you use to build the NavigationViewOptions object with, instead of passing the object itself. The route object can be passed via an intent, as you can convert it to String. The other object is a Boolean. So this will work.

Comment: I used sharedreference and start another activity and solved.